# PDO slow execute() phase when using placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a few JSON-endpoints that return count and group by results. For this endpoint I'm using PDO and named placeholders. When using named placeholders the PHP-response takes up to six seconds during the `execute` phase. When doing the same query and putting the values directly in my query, the response is almost instantaneously.

I'm updating old code that still used mysql_query() to use PDO statements.

```
    <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameOfDB', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("set names utf8");

    $query_slow = "SELECT t.meta as meta, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM field, repo, t, uplink, link  
    WHERE (
        repo.rp1 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp2 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp3 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp4 = field.id)
    AND repo.combination = t.meta 
    AND t.doc_id = uplink.doc_id 
    AND uplink.written = 1 
    AND uplink.link_id = link.id 
    AND field.id = :field 
    AND t.earliest > :min 
    AND t.latest < :max 
    GROUP BY t.meta 
    ORDER BY cnt desc";

    if($parameters){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query_slow);
        $stmt->execute($parameters);
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
    }
```

If I do a `var_dump($parameters)` I get the following returned:

```
    $parameters = array(3) {
      [":field"]=>
      int(5)
      [":min"]=>
      int(-1000)
      [":max"]=>
      int(600)
    }
```

here is the fast query:

```
    $query_fast = "SELECT t.meta as meta, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM field, repo, t, uplink, link  
    WHERE (
        repo.rp1 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp2 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp3 = field.id OR 
        repo.rp4 = field.id)
    AND repo.combination = t.meta 
    AND t.doc_id = uplink.doc_id 
    AND uplink.written = 1 
    AND uplink.link_id = link.id 
    AND field.id=5 
    and t.earliest > -1000 
    and t.latest <600  
    GROUP BY t.meta 
    ORDER BY cnt desc";

    if(1==1){
    // I ditched the $parameters, so my execute is empty.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query_slow);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
    }
```

The slow_query can take up to 6 seconds to run. If I run the same query with the values filled in and an empty `execute()` my response comes almost instantaneously. What did I do wrong with the PDO?

when giving an array to `execute()` my page is slow to respond. When using a query that has not parameters. The response is instantaneous.

My timing code as requested by @RiggsFolly:

So I did a run with timing code in there:

```
    if($parameters){
    $time_prepare = microtime(true);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($querygraph);
    $time_pre_exec = microtime(true);
    $stmt->execute(($parameters));
    //$stmt->execute();
    $time_post_exec = microtime(true);
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $time_post_fetch = microtime(true);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
    }
```

this was with parameters 5, -800 and 800 (the same used earlier). My timing code shows:

```
start:          1563972660.9188      (First line of the script)
prepare:        1563972660.9197        ==$time_prepare
pre execution:  1563972660.9201  ==$time_pre_exec
post execution: 1563972669.0058  ==$time_post_exec ==> 9 seconds!
post fetch:     1563972669.0058
```

when using the same parameters on a query without placeholders, I use the same query and an empty execute(). I replaced the placeholders by the same values I used in the prepared statement. The Timing looks like:

```
prepare:        1563973120.2965
pre execution:  1563973120.2969      //before execution()
post execution: 1563973120.312      //after executeion()
post fetch:     1563973120.3121
```

Comment: Probably wont help with speed bu I use `$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND,'SET NAMES UTF8');`

Comment: Why don't you use a `JOIN` instead?

Comment: I dont see any timing code in here. If you added some it would help identify where the time was being consumed

Comment: try to bind variables separately using appropriate bind types. I doubt it would help but there are some rumos

Comment: first guess: do you have indexes in your tables?

Comment: I recently had an issue in one of my applications which caused things to take a very long time to fetch from the database (as in 5+ minutes, with only around 400 rows in the database), this was because of the use of multiple `OR` blocks inside the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes all indexes are present, first thing I checked. It also wouldn't explain why the query without using placeholders runs much quicker. See my reply to @RiggsFolly with timingcode.

Comment: @Qirel; how would changing the structure of the query to `JOIN` improve the `execute()`phase. If I perform this query in PHPmyadmin or do the same query with values filled in rather then placeholders the speeds is extremely well.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Just found a quirk with the `setAttribute()` you suggested. If I did that, my `json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` failed with an errormessage `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. If I changed that back to my old method of `$conn->exec("set names utf8");` then it worked as expected. The character that caused this was `ü` You wouldn't happen to know on the top of your head why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

For those who have as similar problem; it got fixed by the suggestion by @YourCommonSense.

I had to explicitly use bindValue(); now the entire exection - start to end - takes about 0.02 seconds which is way better than I'd hoped. For dynamically generated queries I changed my code to:

```
$conditions = [];           //values to be inserted by type on placeholder
$parameters = [];           //kind of thing to execute in the query with the placeholder (substring of a query with a named placeholder)
$bindTypes=[];              //the type expected to be for a placeholder (the function takes this as third argument. It should be a long type (strings give errors, hence the if/else if block))
$placeholders=[];           //contains only the :placeholders. Use this to tell the bindvalue() function that you want to bind a value X to placeholder :X 

if(isset($_GET["min"])){
    $mindate = (int)$_GET["min"];
    if($mindate != ""){
        $conditions[] = 't.earliest>= :mindate';
        $parameters[] = $mindate;
        $bindTypes[] = 'int';
        $placeholders[] = ':mindate';
    }
}
if(isset($_GET["max"])){
    $maxdate= (int)$_GET["max"];
    if($maxdate!= ""){
        $conditions[] = 't.latest>= :maxdate';
        $parameters[] = $maxdate;
        $bindTypes[] = 'int';
        $placeholders[] = ':maxdate';
    }
}

if($parameters){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($querygraph);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($placeholders); $i++) {

        if($bindTypes[$i]=='str'){// it's better to use integers as comparison 
            $stmt->bindValue($placeholders[$i], $parameters[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else if($bindTypes[$i]=='int'){
            echo $placeholders[$i];
            $stmt->bindValue($placeholders[$i], $parameters[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }

    } 
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this to you, because MySQL can be really bad at casting types. I had an issue in the past where removing quotes around numeric strings made a huge difference, but in my case I had hundreds of fields. In your case, I think the optimiser could not understand the numeric strings and didn't optimise the query properly. It would be a good idea to ask MySQL to `EXPLAIN` the execution. Also you should really consider what @Qirel told you about JOINs, it could help out the optimiser in some edge cases.

Comment: @Dharman; the funny thing is that even when using `(int)$somevar` in my code; the query was still slow. I now learned that this has to do with standard PDO behaviour: https://github.com/vlucas/spot/issues/4. 

I've only been programming for 2 years; but it's the first time ever I saw this behaviour. Definitely something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Binding values doesn't really affect performance *that* much (a prepared statement does make two round-trips to the database, but the difference in performance is really neglectable). I would rather suggest that you use a `JOIN` query instead - this will simplify your `WHERE` clause too, which *can* be a concern for performance.

You can also specify the charset of the connection object directly, and not bother with the `SET NAMES` query.

If the query is slow, you should look into the indexing of the tables - have you properly used any primary keys on the tables? If yes, you can still throw some indexes to the fields you join on. The IDs of your `field` table and the `doc_id` of your `uplink` table should all be primary keys, for example.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameOfDB;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "SELECT t.meta, COUNT(*) as cnt 
          FROM field AS f 
          JOIN rep AS r
              ON f.id IN (r.rp1, r.rp2, r.rp3, r.rp4)
          JOIN t 
              ON t.meta = r.combination
          JOIN uplink AS u 
              ON u.doc_id = t.doc_id
          JOIN link AS l 
              ON l.id = u.link_id
          WHERE u.written = 1
            AND f.id = :field 
            AND t.earliest > :min 
            AND t.latest < :max 
          GROUP BY t.meta 
          ORDER BY cnt DESC 
          ");

if ($parameters) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameters);
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: I ran the join query with placeholders and the timing is:
    start: 1563975139.986
    prepare: 1563975139.9869
    pre execution: 1563975139.9894
    post execution: 1563975148.3492
    post fetch: 1563975148.3492

When doing the same query without placeholders, my timing is:
    start: 1563975287.6505
    prepare: 1563975287.6512
    pre execution: 1563975287.6537 
    post execution: 1563975287.6831
    post fetch: 1563975287.6831

I don't think the query is to blame, it's got something to do with the `execute()` part but I'm simply not seeing what's wrong.

Comment: @Clueless_captain can't you please add a simple subtraction (round($start-$end)) to your timing to get the time already? Trust me, computers are much better at math than humans

Comment: @YourCommonSense; sure these are the rounded values:
this is for a run with placeholders. I had to use a float with 2 numbers following the dot, since the query itself is actually that fast.:
start: 0
prepare: 0
pre execution: 0
post execution: 8.17
post fetch: 8.17

these are the values for the same query, with the place holders filled in directly. I used the same values:
start: 0
prepare: 0
pre execution: 0
post execution: 0.02
post fetch: 0.02

I went over the JSON output, and it returns me the same data.

Comment: @Clueless_captain you may be missed my suggestion I posted under your question. If you have no other idea you may try it just in case

Comment: @YourCommonSense: You are brilliant!! (I missed the original comment. It took a bit of tinkering to get it working on dynamically generated queries. But now it works. I can't believe no one ever taught me `bindValues()` for dynamic queries. Thanks so much, you're a lifesaver! (How do I make your comment an answer so others can find it?)

Comment: @Clueless_captain you can write your own answer. I will mention it in my PHP tutorial, as it's the first time I have a confirmation from someone for [this behavior](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#methods) (see point two).